# How to debug test and additional projects at the same time

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a web app, and a set of unit tests. I need to debug both at the same time.
In VS2010 all was simple - I just started my unit test, and debug of the web app was attached automatically. In VS2012 this is no longer working. Web app is running, but is not being debugged. Any ideas, how I can debug both at the same time?

Comment: are unit tests in same or different project as web app?

Comment: they are in different projects of the same solution, as it's usually done.

Comment: the process attached to debugger might need checking and verify that if you are able to debug both web app and unit tests hitting F5 in VS2010, are they attached to same process or different which might not be happening in vs2012. Sometimes if we are debugging webapp and then start another application in same solution e.g a winform it grabs web app process and we are unable to debug web app unless winform app is detached. can you verify if right process is attached and compare it with vs2010 case?

Comment: Obviously they are different processes. Probably you shouldn't answer the question, if you don't understand it.

Comment: sorry couldn't understand your question then. Good Luck.

Comment: You didn't know, that debugger can attach to multiple processes?

Answer (score 1):

Set the web-app as the start-up project within your solution now start the unit test (assuming they are in class library project). This seems to work for me, If I dont have the web-app set as the start-up project I get an error when debuging/starting the Unit Tests(sayuing no executable project is refrenced).

Comment: I already have the web app set as "start project". Not working.

Comment: In your tests project In Properties -> Debug Tab , do you have Start Action set as Start Project ? Does everything compile ok when you build the whole solution ?

Comment: YES and YES. this is obvious.

Comment: Sorry but another Obvious thing I face this issue when my Web-App is in 'Release' configuration and not 'Debug' in Build - Configuration Manager.

Comment: no release. all in debug. obviously ;) and I have to note, that in .net - release applications can be debugged as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2012, I tried attaching all the processes while debugging the unit tests. That worked for me but I couldn't find something automatic.